# Ant jar task to include applicationContext.xml file

Tags: java, spring, ant

I have a spring class with main method. Inside the class am trying to read the values applicationContext.xml . My intention is to jar this main class along with its dependant jars,property files and applicationContext.xml .Hence i have my target as below

```
 <target name="testing" depends="init">
    <property name="mech.dir" value="${target.dir}/MECHNSM" />
    <property name="mech.classes.dir" value="${mech.dir}/classes" />
    <delete dir="${mech.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${mech.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${mech.classes.dir}" />
    <copy file="${tests.dir}/Mechanism.properties"      todir="${mech.classes.dir}" overwrite="true" />
    <copy file="${tests.dir}/applicationContext.xml" todir="${mech.classes.dir}" overwrite="true" />
    <javac destdir="${mech.classes.dir}" debug="true" classpath="/jars/dependency_jars/spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" classpathref="project.class.path">
        <src path="${tests.dir}"/>
        <include name="com/test/Sample.java" />
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="${retymech.dir}/retryOrderPerformPost.jar" basedir="${retymech.classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.test.Sample"/>
        </manifest>
        <!--<zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />-->
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/log4j.jar" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/httpmime-4.1.3.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/httpclient-cache-4.1.3.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/httpcore-4.1.4.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />
        <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/httpclient-4.1.3.jar" includes="**/*.class" excludes="META-INF/**/*" />

        <fileset dir="${tests.dir}" includes="applicationContext.xml" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

But when i try to run the Sample.jar file, it looks like the applicationContext file is not getting loaded. Am i doing anything wrong here. Please send me your suggestions.

Comment: Is that `applicationContext.xml` file in your Jar? Examine the resulting jar. If you're on Windows, use 7zip or Winzip to examine the jar. If you're on Unix, you can use `jar tvf retryOrderPerformPost.jar` | grep "applicationContext\.xml"` to see if your XML file is included and is in the root of the jar. If it  is, you don't have an Ant issue, but a Java issue. You'll need to retag your question and rephrase it for someone who understands Java to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I used winrar and went inside the jar and was able to see the applicationContext.xml file .Hence as you said this should be a java issue.So let me retag the question..

Comment: Am able to  read the applicationContext file.But am getting exception saying --- Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinit
ionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHan
dler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]               ....    Could you please help me on this